# On writing jQuery Plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've written my fourth plugin now and I'm starting to notice a trend in my development pattern and not sure if theres a better way to handle it.

I'm using the Plugin method (lightweight start pattern outlined by Addy Osmani, see here: http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#jquerypluginpatterns)

In my Plugin.prototype, I have a bunch of methods including the init() function which I use to call all the methods in the plugin.  Pardon the confusion, but this is what it would look like:

```
Plugin.prototype = {
init: function() {
this.doMethodOne();
this.doMethodTwo(this.element, this.options)
this.doMethodThree();
},

doMethodOne: function() { .. }
doMethodTwo: function(el, options) { .. }
doMethodThree: function() { .. }

}

$.fn[pluginName] = function ( options ) {
        return this.each(function () {
            if (!$.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName)) {
                $.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName, 
                new Plugin( this, options ));
            }
        });
    }
```

I left out some of the envelope code but I hope you get the idea.

I find my code a little lacking because I'm pretty much just calling my code linearly and storing it in a plugin namespace.

I've read the plugin development patterns and authoring text many times, and still write this way.  How can I improve this?

Thanks !

Comment: What do you want to improve about it?

Comment: Since this isn't really a problem but a question about a better way to write code you may want to post this over on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I just find I am repeating myself with the this.method calls.  I also wanted to call a sibling method from another method, and couldn't figure it out.  How do you do it?